# Customize Walker_nav_menu to show posts if item is category

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I would like to customize the nav menu walker so that when it encounters a category it automatically makes the 5 most resent posts children of the menu item.  Is there a way to dynamically add items to the menu object or it better to have a conditional in the start_el function?

Comment: `start_el`-- aka, extend the walker.

Answer (score 0):

You could either extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` walker class (i.e., the `start_el` function is sufficient, as already mentioned).
Or you could hook in when the original output (i.e., the category) has been created. That would be the [`walker_nav_menu_start_el`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L169) hook.

For instance like so:

```
function wpdev_139801_start_el( $item_output, $item ) {
    if ( isset( $item->object ) && $item->object === 'category' ) {
        // Set up your query here,
        // then concatenate the output to $item_output
        // You could do this using wp_get_archives()
    }

    return $item_output;
} // function wpdev_139801_start_el

add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpdev_139801_start_el', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This will add the posts in a list if I choose but will not put the posts threw the walker.  Therefore the posts will not have the same classes that the Walker_nav_menu puts on the elements by default.  Will I just have to manually add those classes in the wpdev_139801_start_el function after my query when contructing my ouput?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I see what you are trying to do. I didn't think about actually including the category posts into the walker output. To do so, you might want to use some other hook, and adjust the actual objects for the walker function. Have a look at the [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L549) hook.

Comment: I was looking at the nav menu object itself.  Dynamically creating objects and inserting them was kind of what I was think but didn't know if that was possible. Specifically because the dynamically created item would not have an Object ID that corresponded to anything with a nav_menu taxonomy.

Comment: Well, yes, if you add your 5 (or so) posts to the nav menu items they won't have an item ID (in terms of the CSS class). But all the other (relevant) classes can/will be generated without a problem.